# Python nosetests: how to access cmd line options? Namely `--failed`

Tags: python, testing, command-line-arguments, nosetests, args

**Running**: Windows 7, python 3.4 & 2.7

In one of my nosetests plugin, (one that post test data to a website), I need to ascertain if the test is being run with the `--failed` option or without.  If `--failed` is enabled, that means this test failed the first time and is being run once more to see if that fail was a fluke.  If this is a re-run of a failed test I need to direct my plugin to some different behavior vs. if the test is being run for the first time.

In other words, I want to ascertain inside the plugin if we are inside `nosetests` or `nosetests --failed`.

How can I access `nosetest`'s command line options from inside a plug in?  What variable are the options stored in?

My eventual code will look something like this:

```
 if <--failed option was invoked with nosetests command>: 
     do something
 else:
     do something different
```

What's the correct code to replace  what's inside `<>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand, but the command line arguments part is easy. Just use the following code:

```
from sys import argv as arguments

if "--failed" in arguments :
    do_something()
else :
    do_something_else()
```

When you import [sys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html), you have access to the [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

Comment: Seems like that works so far.  I had thought that a module could only access the cmd arguements that way if THE MODULE ITSELF was called from the command line.  In this situation, where a batch file is calling `nosetests` which is calling `plugin.py`, I had assumed the cmd args got stuck higher up close to the original cmd ln call.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to grab command line arguments is the system library

```py
import sys

sys.argv #this is a list of args sys.argv[0] is the program itself
```

so it would be

```
if sys.argv[1] == '--failed':
```